# How can you determine direction of spin-1/2 states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, vectors, quantum-states, bloch-sphere

How do you determine the direction of the state of a spin-1/2 particle? For instance, given the quantum state $|\psi\rangle=(1,0)$, where does this vector point in space? I would say that it points in the $x$-direction given the usual definition of vectors.

But what about a quantum state like $|\phi\rangle=(1,\sqrt{2}-1)$? Where can we say that this vector points in space?

Comment: depends on what exactly $(1,0)$ means...it could also mean e.g. spin-up state in $z$-direction.

Comment: The state space is not the physical 3D space we live in. $|\psi\rangle$ itself doesn't point anywhere in physical space.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović spin 1/2 states do have a direction in 3D space. Standard basis of spin 1/2 Hilbert space refers to cartesian coordinate system axes, and any spin state $s$ has a unique Pauli vector $\sigma_s$ for which $s$ is its eigenvector with eigenvalue 1. Thus spin states are associated with single direction, and can be thought of as living on a sphere in the coordinate system.

Comment: @JánLalinský I was trying to make a distinction between a vector in Hilbert space and the corresponding direction in physical 3D space. From the text of the question, it seems like the OP is conflating the two, and this is causing their confusion. The OP wrote that (1, 0) "points in the x-direction given the usual definition of vectors", and I'm just pointing out that the state vector itself, as a mathematical construct, doesn't live in physical space, and therefore neither does this "x" direction.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović OK, but "does not live in physical space" does not mean "doesn't point anywhere in physical space". Spin state does "point" in single direction in space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual representation of spin $1/2$ operators by Pauli matrices implies that the state $|\psi\rangle = (1,0)^{tr}$ corresponds to a spin oriented in the positive direction of the $z$ axis. This is due to
$$
\sigma^z |\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle
$$
To find the orientation of the spin in an arbitrary state described by the vector $(x,y)^{tr}$, you need to find the polar and azimuthal angles $\vartheta$ and $\varphi$, such that the vector $(x,y)^{tr}$ was the eigenvector of the matrix
$$
\cos(\vartheta)\ \sigma^z + \sin(\vartheta)\cos(\varphi)\ \sigma^x + \sin(\vartheta)\sin(\varphi)\ \sigma^y
$$
with the eigenvalue of $1$. Or, equivalently, you need to represent the vector as $(x,y)^{tr} = A(\cos(\vartheta/2), e^{i\varphi}\sin(\vartheta/2))^{tr}$. For example, the vector $|\phi\rangle = (1, \sqrt{2}-1)^{tr}$ corresponds to spin oriented in the $xz$-plane along the direction defined by angles $\vartheta = 2\arctan(\sqrt{2}-1)$, $\varphi = 0$.

Answer (score 10):

The Hilbert space of a spin 1/2 degree of freedom is spanned by orthogonal vectors $\left| \uparrow \right>$ and $\left| \downarrow \right>$.

These vectors are the common eigenvectors of the two operators $\vec S^2$ and $S_z$ (where $\vec S = (S_x, S_y, S_z)$ is the spin operator):
$$ S_z \left| \uparrow \right> = \frac \hbar 2 \left| \uparrow \right>  $$
$$ S_z \left| \downarrow \right> = -\frac \hbar 2  \left| \downarrow \right>$$
$$ \vec S^2 \left| \uparrow \right> = \frac 3 4 \hbar^2 \left|\uparrow\right> $$
$$ \vec S^2 \left| \downarrow \right> = \frac 3 4 \hbar^2 \left|\downarrow\right> $$

(This, more or less, falls out of analyzing the commutation algebra of the angular momentum operators.)

If you now write something like $\left| \psi \right> = (\alpha, \beta)$ or more commonly $\left| \psi \right> = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix}$, what you mean is the vector $\alpha \left|\uparrow\right> + \beta \left|\downarrow \right>$. To obtain a normalized state vector we, of course, have to have $\alpha \alpha^* + \beta \beta^* = 1$.

In this basis the spin operator $\vec S$ can be represented in terms of the standard Pauli matrices $\vec S = \frac \hbar 2 \vec \sigma$, where
$$\sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$
$$\sigma_y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$
$$\sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

This vector space is not immediately related to our normal space $\mathbb{R}^3$, so the directions in this vector space can't be interpreted as $x$ and $y$. Rather, the direction of an arbitrary state $\left|\psi\right> = (\alpha, \beta)$ is obtained as follows.

We can always find a unit vector $\vec e$, sucht that $(\vec e \cdot \vec S) \left| \psi \right> = \frac \hbar 2 \left| \psi \right>$. That is, there is a projection of the spin operator along a unit vector for which the state is an eigenvector. This is the direction the spin points to, just as $\left|\uparrow\right>$ points along the $z$-axis. (One procedure to find this vector $\vec e$ is described in the answer by @Gec.)

Of course, you have to be careful: When measuring the spin along another direction, you will also get the values $\pm \frac \hbar 2$. If the direction is orthogonal to our $\vec e$ both will have the same probability $\frac 1 2$.

Comment: "That is, there is a projection of the spin operator along a unit vector for which the state is an eigenvector." Of course, it would then also be an eigenvector of the projection onto $-\vec e$.

Comment: @Accumulation Yes, but with eigenvalue $-\hbar/2$, I should probably make that clearer in the text.

Answer (score 4):

There is a misapprehension in the OP. Vectors in the spin Hilbert space don't point in real space, because they don't *live* in real space.  This is true of a vector in *any* quantum state space.  The "direction" of a Hilbert space vector is along that vector in the Hilbert space, and if this vector space is not the "vector space of positions in real space" (not really a vector space, but nevermind that), then the vectors in this space don't point in any direction.

That said, we can always put a physical spin (pun intended) on the state of a quantum system. If we compute expectation values of the three spin component operators $\hat{S}_x$, $\hat{S}_y$, and $\hat{S}_z$ and construct the spin vector in real-space, i.e.,
$$
\langle\hat{S}_x\rangle\,\hat{x}+\langle\hat{S}_y\rangle\,\hat{y}+\langle\hat{S}_z\rangle\,\hat{z}\,,
$$
where $\hat{x}$, etc. are the three unit vectors in real space, then we can think of this vector as the direction in which the spin points (on average, of course, because these are expectation values).

(The expectation values are computed as, for instance, $\langle \psi | \hat{S}_x | \psi \rangle$, where $|\psi\rangle$ is the quantum state.)

Comment: "Vectors in the spin Hilbert space don't point in real space"

Often they do -- or at least _correspond_ to pointing in real space.  And that's all you can expect from a mathematical abstraction.  If you describe an electron with a spinor, the electron really does have a spin about an axis, and it's a real spin that couples with orbital angular momentum and is jointly conserved.   Sure, any two level system can also be described with 2-level Hilbert space -- but those spaces shouldn't be described as spin Hilbert spaces except as an analog.  A useful analog, granted.

Answer (score 4):

There are already some good answers here, but no one gave you the formula for how to turn the normalized spin-1/2 state
$$|\psi>=\pmatrix{a\\b}$$
into the corresponding vector on the Bloch sphere, pointing in the direction of a certain spin result.  In other words, the direction in which a spin-measurement would always yield $+\hbar/2$.

For any spin-1/2 state, that direction is the unit vector
$$ 2 Re(ab^*) \hat{x} - 2 Im(ab^*) \hat{y} + (aa^*-bb^*)\hat{z}$$.

Representing spin-1/2 states in this way is what is known as the "Bloch sphere" representation.

Note: Your example of $a=1$, $b=\sqrt{2}-1$ won't work with this unless you first normalize the state.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask where/how you derived the formula to connect between spin quantum states and direction in cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Note: The answer by @march contains the same formula in a different guise (up to a factor of $\hbar/2$).

Comment: The basic idea is to write the density matrix $|\psi><\psi|$ in terms of $a$ and $b$, and then set this equal to $1/2( I + \vec{n} \cdot \vec{\sigma})$, where $\sigma$ is the vector of Pauli matrices.  $\vec{n}$ is the vector on the Bloch sphere.

Answer (score 1):

*T.L;D.R. the spin doesn't have a well-defined direction*

> $\ldots$ I would say that it points in the x-direction given the usual definition of vectors.

That to me suggests you are thinking of the spin state $|\psi\rangle=(a,b)^{[1]}$, to be a vector in the $2D$ coordinate plane. That is incorrect. Spin angular momentum $\mathbf{S}$ is a $3D$ vector quantity. Its component along *any one* arbitrarily chosen direction can be known at a time. By convention, that direction is labelled as the $z$-axis. Since the $z$ component operator  $\hat{S_z}$ is an observable, its eigenstates themselves form an [abstract vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) (in particular a [Hilbert space](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HilbertSpace.html)). For spin $s$ particles, that space is $(2s+1)D$ (so $2D$ for spin $1/2$, but would be $5D$ for, say $s=2$, even though $\mathbf{S}$ would still be three dimensional for both spins). $(a,b)$ is a normalized vector in *that* space. In this state, $S_z$ is measured to be $+1/2(-1/2)^{[2]}$ with probability $a^2(b^2)$. If you find any of this discussion unfamiliar, maybe you would like to review the topic of spin before reading on.

For simplicity, let$^{[3]}$ the state be $(1,0)$ i.e. the $z$-component of $\mathbf{S}$ is *always* found to be $+1/2$ upon measurement. So, what is the direction of $\mathbf{S}$ ? **It is not defined**. To know the direction we need to also know the components along the $x$ and $y$ axes *simultaneously*. Since observables $\hat{S_x}$ and $\hat{S_y}$ are [incompatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson%E2%80%93Schr%C3%B6dinger_uncertainty_relations) with $\hat{S_z}$, this is impossible. Furthermore, even by chance, we could not have picked a direction that was alligned to $\mathbf{S}$ for this requires that $S_x$ and $S_y$ have definite values (but haven't been measured yet) which implies a [realist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_locality#Quantum_mechanics) interpretation of quantum states not supported by [Bell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem).

Can we claim that $\mathbf{S}$ is along the $z$-axis, since afterall, the particle is in an eigenstate of $\hat{S_z}$? No, because perfect allignment with the $z$-axis would require both $S_x$ and $S_y$ to be $0$ - a value they aren't allowed to take since it's neither's eigenvalue (never mind the previous discussion about compatibility). What about an integral spin ($S_x$ and $S_y$ are allowed to be $0$ then)? Still no, since the maximum value of $S_z(s)$ is always less than the magnitude of $S(\sqrt{s(s+1)})$ so $S_x$ and $S_y$ couldn't both be zero.

For the general state $(a,b)$ the situation is even worse since even the component along $z$-axis is unknown - it could be either $\pm 1/2$.

The truly quantum mechanical angular momentum doesn't have a well defined direction. The most that can be said about directionality is the component along one, and only one, but arbitrary direction. However, this doesn't prevent one from creating some effective notion of the spin's direction (see [@march's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/780021/226560)), though it bears no connection to a direction for $\mathbf{S}$.

---

$^{[1]}$ Since the question doesn't specify, we assume $|\psi\rangle$ to just be the spin part, ignoring Hamiltonian dynamics.

$^{[2]}$ in units where $\hbar=1$

$^{[3]}$ This is to say we took a bunch of identical spin $1/2$ particles and *prepared* them to be in the state $(a,b)$ (here $(1,0)$) e.g. using [Stern-Gerlach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment) apparatus(es), in which case the magnetic field gradient direction would *define* the $z$-axis.